# TravisCI - ERR : Package flute_music_player requires Flutter SDK version ^0.1.2 but the current SDK is 0.0.0-unknown

Tags: travis-ci, flutter, flutter-test

I am new travis and started working on it with flutter.

I am using flute_music_player [plugin](https://github.com/iampawan/Flute-Music-Player)  for my music player app.

Now app is working/building fine locally on my machine but I cant build it on Travis

Here is what I get

```
    $ ./flutter/bin/flutter test
    Running "flutter packages get" in tumultus...             
    Package flute_music_player requires Flutter SDK version ^0.1.2 but the current SDK is 0.0.0-unknown.
    ---- Log transcript ----
.
.
.
.
---- End log transcript ----
pub get failed (1)
The command "./flutter/bin/flutter test" exited with 1.
store build cache
nothing changed, not updating cache
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Here is the link to my complete Job  [log.](https://travis-ci.org/iamSahdeep/tumultus/builds/364675749)

And my travis.yml is :

```
os:
  - linux
sudo: false
addons:
  apt:
    # Flutter depends on /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 version GLIBCXX_3.4.18
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test # if we don't specify this, the libstdc++6 we get is the wrong version
    packages:
      - libstdc++6
      - fonts-droid
before_script:
  - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b alpha --depth 1
  - ./flutter/bin/flutter doctor
script:
  - ./flutter/bin/flutter test
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.pub-cache
```

My complete project can be found on github [here](https://github.com/iamSahdeep/tumultus)

Actually I have copied most of the code from [here](https://github.com/iampawan/Flutter-Music-Player) and I tried to run his project on travis but same error on log.

Is there anywhere I am lacking, please help.

Thanks for any help or suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright the Issue was with plugin version not actually Travis.